# Is it possible to write an AWS Lambda function using Java without Maven (or Gradle, etc.)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-lambda

We have a legacy Java project we might run as an AWS lambda function. However, this project does not use Maven, and we are not very interested (read: hard pass) in adding Maven to it, in any form. (We do not use Java for new projects, and have no desire to add complexities.)

Is there a way to run a Java project in lambda without using Maven?

Comment: It will take 10 minutes to get Maven or Gradle running.  It will take you hours to manually build a Lambda and properly package it.

Comment: How do you build your Java code now - a shell/batch script?

Comment: If you do not use Maven or Gradle - you need to manually add JARs to your class path. As stated above - its 10 mins to setup a Maven project vs hours of trying to hunt down the proper JARS and adding them to your class path.

Comment: Why do you hate Maven?

Answer (score 2):

I would still suggest to use a tool like Maven or Gradle to manage all dependencies. If you really insist, you can package the ZIP file containing all class files in the root of the ZIP, and all required libraries in folder called 'lib' in the ZIP file:

```
Main.class
Another.class
lib/
  mysql.jar
  otherlib.jar
```

You can upload this ZIP to the AWS console. For more information see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-package.html